# how to combine two different values from one table of one customer into one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to list out the ID's that have ordered different codes. I dont want to list ID which ordered only one code(i.e. ID 4, 5).

```
ID      product      code
1       Apple        145
1       Grapes       146
2       Orange       147
2       Apple        145
2       Plum         148 
3       Grapes       146
3       Orange       147
4       Grapes       146
5       Orange       147
```

And I want it to look like this

```
ID      Codes       
1     145 | 146
2     147 | 145 | 148
3     146 | 147
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: oracle database.

Comment: @c.kan What version of Oracle? Functions improved and were added over time.

Comment: Sorry, Oracle Database 10g

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY id`, and the condition on "more than one order" goes into a `HAVING` clause (because it is a constraint on each group, not on each individual row in the input data). The aggregation is done with `LISTAGG`.

```
with
     test_data ( id, product, code ) as (
       select 1, 'Apple' , 145 from dual union all
       select 1, 'Grapes', 146 from dual union all
       select 2, 'Orange', 147 from dual union all
       select 2, 'Apple' , 145 from dual union all
       select 2, 'Plum'  , 148 from dual union all
       select 3, 'Grapes', 146 from dual union all
       select 3, 'Orange', 147 from dual union all
       select 4, 'Grapes', 146 from dual union all
       select 5, 'Orange', 147 from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). Query begins below this line.
select   id, listagg(code, ' | ') within group (order by id) as codes
from     test_data
group by id
having   count(*) > 1
;

ID  CODE
--  ---------------
 1  145 | 146
 2  145 | 147 | 148
 3  146 | 147
```

However, in Oracle 10 you don't have `LISTAGG()`. Before Oracle 11.2, a common way to get the same result was to use hierarchical queries, something like below:

```
select id, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(code, ' | '), ' | ') as codes
from   (
         select id, code,
                row_number() over (partition by id order by code) as rn
         from   test_data
       )
where connect_by_isleaf = 1 and level > 1
connect by rn = prior rn + 1
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
start with rn = 1
;
```

**EDITED**:

If repeated CODE for the same ID need to be "distincted" first, then - using the second solution - the following changes are needed, both in the innermost subquery:

- change `SELECT ID, CODE, ...`   to   `SELECT` **`DISTINCT`** `ID, CODE, ...`
- change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `DENSE_RANK()`

Comment: @c.kan - I don't understand; the first version I posted should not have worked for you, because you said you use Oracle 10 and `LISTAGG()` does not exist in Oracle 10. Then: What do you mean by "multiple duplicate values"? There is no mention of that in your question. Do you mean, if the same CODE appears more than once, you want it counted only once? Please clarify the requirement IN YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION.

Comment: My bad, i looked into wrong table. it gave me multiple values which was expected. Your query works perfectly fine.

Comment: One quick question. How can i avoid duplicates. Like, 
1       Apple        145
1       Grapes       146
1       Grapes       146

Now, i want to print only 145, 146 and not 145, 146, 146

Comment: @c.kan - so, are you using the first solution (with `LISTAGG`) - which means you are NOT using Oracle 10 - or the second solution, with `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`? And then, if you have an ID that ordered a single CODE, but more than once (like, ID = 5 ordered Orange three times, but never ordered anything else) should they still be excluded? All these situations can be handled easily, but you need to be precise with the requirements.

Comment: i am using second solution.

Comment: @c.kan - OK, I edited my answer - at the bottom you will find the changes needed to make this work with duplicate codes for the same id.

Comment: Awesome thanks much. My apology for extended questions. Since, i am new i did not put my questions at once. What if i want to pull only for particular CODE orders. meaning: i want to pull only 145 and 147 only. I want to include condition.
<pre>ID      product      code
1       Apple        145
1       Grapes       146
1       Orange       147
1       Apple        145