# Merge different record of same employee in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display a data in such a way that for single employee, there is multiple charge i,e current or Additional charge and, I need to merge the column for those employee who are currently having additional charge along with current charge, i wrote a query, which fetches the record.

```
       SELECT 
DISTINCT ost.EMP_ID,
E.name emp_name,
E.EMP_CODE emloyee_code,
L.NAME Official_loc,
DEP.name DEPARTMENT_NAME,
LISTAGG(DEP.name,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DEP.name )DEPARTMENT_NAME,
D.NAME DESIGNATION_NAME, 
ost.UPDATE_BY,
ost.UPDATE_DATE,
ost.UPDATE_BY_NAME,
LISTAGG(ost.CHARGE,'|')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ost.CHARGE) AS CHARGE,
--ost.CHARGE,
ost.OFFICIAL_LOCATION_ID,
ost.STATUS 
FROM ORG_STRUCTURE_TAGGING ost
JOIN EMPLOYEE E 
ON E.EMP_ID=ost.EMP_ID
LEFT JOIN DESIGNATION D
ON D.DESIGNATION_ID=ost.DESIGNATION_ID
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT DEP
ON DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID=ost.DEPARTMENT_ID
LEFT JOIN LOCATION L
ON L.LOCATION_ID=ost.OFFICIAL_LOCATION_ID
WHERE ost.STATUS=1 
group by ost.EMP_ID, E.name, E.EMP_CODE, L.NAME, DEP.name, 
ost.DESIGNATION_ID, D.NAME, ost.UPDATE_BY, ost.UPDATE_DATE, ost.UPDATE_BY_NAME, 
ost.OFFICIAL_LOCATION_ID, ost.STATUS
```

OUTPUT:

```
614 Abraham Oommen  1541032 Corporate Office    National Events Computer Operator   11-JAN-19   Super Administrator Additional Charge
633 Mukesh R Sharma 1051009 Corporate Office    Content Management (National Events)    Executive Director  14-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
686 Nousara Khadka  1051019 Corporate Office    Content Management (National Events)    Executive Engineer  11-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
688 Prem Lal Namdeo 1051029 Corporate Office    Pre & Post Allotment    Computer Operator   11-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
364 Kumari Sapna    1031036 Corporate Office    Events & Roadshows (International Events)   Manager 15-JAN-19   Super Administrator Additional Charge
364 Kumari Sapna    1031036 Corporate Office    Events & Roadshows (International Events)   Computer Operator   14-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
614 Abraham Oommen  1541032 Corporate Office    Content Management (International Events)   Assistant Grade 2   11-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
469 Pooja Bhimte    1071025 Corporate Office    Content Management (International Events)   Chief General Manager   14-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
242 Vijay Sugandhi  1023014 Corporate Office    Allotment   Executive Engineer  15-JAN-19   Super Administrator Current Charge
686 Nousara Khadka  1051019 Corporate Office    Procurement Senior Accountant   11-JAN-19   Super Administrator Additional Charge
```

As per output for single employee we have two designation and charge, I want to merge it as single column and keep their values comma separated.

for Eg: EMP ID 614 has two record

```
EMP ID, EMP_NAME,    EMP_CODE,     LOCATION,         DESIGNATION,  ASSIGNED SECTION
    614 Abraham Oommen  1541032 Corporate Office    Content Management (International Events),National Events   "Assistant Grade 2-->current Charge,Computer Operator--> Additional Charge"

DESIGNATION should be output as "Content Management (International Events),National Events Computer Operator"

ASSIGNED_SECTION should be output as "Assistant Grade 2-current Charge,Computer Operator- Additional Charge"
```

As of now, those values belongs to same employee but are in different columns, i want to merge it, kindly suggest me the solution for it.

```
TABLE STRUCTURE:

ORG_STRUCTURE_TAGGING_ID    NUMBER  Yes     1   
EMP_ID  NUMBER  Yes     2   
DEPARTMENT_ID   VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)    Yes     3   
DESIGNATION_ID  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   Yes     4   
UPDATE_BY   NUMBER  Yes     5   
UPDATE_DATE DATE    Yes     6   
UPDATE_BY_NAME  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     7   
CHARGE  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     8   
OFFICIAL_LOCATION_ID    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)    Yes     9   
STATUS  NUMBER  Yes     10  
ENTRY_BY    NUMBER  Yes     11  
ENTRY_DATE  DATE    Yes     12  
APPROVED_BY NUMBER  Yes     13  
APPROVED_DATE   DATE    Yes     14
```

Comment: You should take a look at [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

Comment: kindly demonstrate it by considering my use case

Comment: How are you determining the `assigned_section` construction - how do you know which is 'current' and which 'additional'? And what will happen if there are more than two rows for an employee?

Comment: @user10753505 we are not here to do your job for you - why don't you give it a go and then if you are still stuck, update your question with what you've tried and we can help you further?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I have maintained CHARGE column in my table, and employee can have only single current charge but can have multiple Additional Charge

Comment: @user10753505 take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055043/how-to-combine-two-different-values-from-one-table-of-one-customer-into-one-row; that shows how you can achieve your aim.

Comment: @Boneist just updated the same, but no expected output produces

Comment: @user10753505 You need to also update the output your new query gives you and show how it differs from what you're expecting.

Comment: Same output, that's why I am not updated the output

Comment: @user10753505 - your output doesn't seem to include all the columns from the query, which is a little confusing. It would help if it showed the column headings and if it was aligned properly too. However, I think you need to remove `DEP.name` from the group-by clause, since you're aggregating that column now. You also seem to want to aggregate `D.NAME`? Or eventually aggregate the concatenated name and charge, but one step at a time...

Comment: I do, but it throws not a group by expression, then I remove the column name d.name, but still my output is not achieved as I expected.

Comment: Right, because you haven't commented out the first `DEP.name DEPARTMENT_NAME` when you added the aggregated version (like you did for the charge). And once you have done that, it's still not as you expected because you have plain columns (`D.NAME`) that you also need to aggregate. Probably - it's hard to tell without the actual current query and output. Also bear in mind that we can't see your raw data or even table structures.

Comment: recently I update the query and also the table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your query, whose results should match your expected output.

As explained in the comments, every non-aggregated column must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, while aggregated columns should not appear in the `GROUP BY`. In the query that you have showed, column `DEP.name` is aggregated with `LISTAGG` but also present in the `GROUP BY` : as a consequence, no aggregation actually happens.

I removed all `SELECT`ed fields that do no appear in your expected result (such as `CHARGE` for example) and used `LISTAGG` to aggregate :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ost.EMP_ID,
    E.name emp_name,
    E.EMP_CODE emloyee_code,
    L.NAME Official_loc,
    LISTAGG(DEP.name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DEP.name) DESIGNATION,
    LISTAGG(D.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.name) ASSIGNED_SECTION
FROM 
    ORG_STRUCTURE_TAGGING ost
    JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.EMP_ID=ost.EMP_ID
    LEFT JOIN DESIGNATION D ON D.DESIGNATION_ID=ost.DESIGNATION_ID
    LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT DEP ON DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID=ost.DEPARTMENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN LOCATION L ON L.LOCATION_ID=ost.OFFICIAL_LOCATION_ID
WHERE 
    ost.STATUS=1 
GROUP BY 
    ost.EMP_ID,
    E.name,
    E.EMP_CODE,
    L.NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the more complicated output you said you were looking for, you seem to want something like this:

```
select
  ost.emp_id,
  e.name emp_name,
  e.emp_code emloyee_code,
  l.name official_loc,
  listagg(dep.name, ',')
    within group (order by dep.name) as departments,
  listagg(d.name || '-' || ost.charge, ',')
    within group (order by ost.charge desc, d.name) as designations,
  ost.update_by,
  ost.update_date,
  ost.update_by_name,
  ost.status 
from org_structure_tagging ost
join employee e on e.emp_id=ost.emp_id
left join designation d on d.designation_id=ost.designation_id
left join department dep on dep.department_id=ost.department_id
left join location l on l.location_id=ost.official_location_id
where ost.status=1 
group by 
  ost.emp_id, 
  e.name, 
  e.emp_code, 
  l.name, 
  ost.update_by, 
  ost.update_date, 
  ost.update_by_name, 
  ost.status;
```

I may have the column names in the wrong order as it isn't clear which is which from your output. But this is doing a simple aggregation of department name, and a slightly more complicated aggregation of the *concatenated* designation and charge values.

Or to prevent duplicates, use a subquery which applies `distinct` before aggregating:

```
select
  emp_id,
  emp_name,
  employee_code,
  official_loc,
  listagg(department, ',')
    within group (order by department) as departments,
  listagg(designation || '-' || charge, ',')
    within group (order by charge desc, designation) as designations,
  update_by,
  update_date,
  update_by_name,
  status 
from(
  select distinct
    ost.emp_id,
    e.name emp_name,
    e.emp_code employee_code,
    l.name official_loc,
    dep.name as department,
    d.name as designation,
    ost.charge,
    ost.update_by,
    ost.update_date,
    ost.update_by_name,
    ost.status 
  from org_structure_tagging ost
  join employee e on e.emp_id=ost.emp_id
  left join designation d on d.designation_id=ost.designation_id
  left join department dep on dep.department_id=ost.department_id
  left join location l on l.location_id=ost.official_location_id
  where ost.status=1
)
group by 
  emp_id, 
  emp_name, 
  employee_code, 
  official_loc,
  update_by, 
  update_date, 
  update_by_name, 
  status;
```